# Adding a custom URL to the top of a view based on status of another field

Tags: views, 6

Okay... so I have this crazy problem. Not really, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have a view, that lists out a content type "request". When you click on the title, it links to that node (also displayed using a view).

So what I'm trying to do is this:
When on a node whose content type is "request", I need to dynamically create a link that uses the title.

For example, if the Node is http://www.example.com/request/this%20is%20the%20title

Then I'd like a link to appear of this form: 
http://www.example.com/survey?request=this%20is%20the%20title

BUT ONLY if that node has a field_type_status of "closed"

Summary:
Dynamically create a link using node's title using a view based on a field's status.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually several questions. I'd suggest that you break you problem down into smaller, more manageable questions otherwise the number of responses might be low.

For starters, a break down:

- "I need to dynamically create a link that uses the title" -> 
  [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.
- "I'd like a link to appear of this form": The
  format that the URLs appear in can be set in the Pathauto
  configuration settings for the node type.
- "BUT ONLY if that node has a field_type_status of "closed" -> Hmmm,
  this might require some custom code. It's kind of a weird spec as
  it's considered good SEO to use Pathauto on all site content. Good
  luck with this one, perhaps someone else will help you with this one.